# JavaFX ProgressBar animation or transition

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

I'm currently working on a JavaFX progress bar, setting the progress with `setProgress()`. I'd like to know if there is a way to animate the `setProgress()` progress like with a transition or something like that. I'd like to animate jumps like from 30% to 90%. Is this possible?

Code currently looks like this:

```
@FXML
private ProgressBar pbStart;    
// ...
pbStart.setProgress(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

The values of the progress property can be set and animated using a `Timeline` animation:

```
pbStart.setProgress(0.3);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(pbStart.progressProperty(), 0.9);
KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000), keyValue);
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);

timeline.play();
```